# How to delete and draw new button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint


def get_numbers():
    global numbers
    numbers = [randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(20)]
    print(numbers)
    draw_buttons()


def draw_buttons():
    for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
        button = Button(text=str(number), command=lambda: get_numbers())
        button.grid(row=0, column=i)


numbers = []
get_numbers()
root = Tk()
draw_buttons()
root.mainloop()
```

And when I run it it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I want it to update the buttons. Every time I click any button, it draws new buttons over the old ones with new numbers. This doesnt look good as you can see in second image. What I want is to delete old button before drawing new. How can I do that?

Comment: Your title says you want to delete and recreate a button, but the body of the text says you want to update the buttons. Which do you want to do? You can change the text without deleting and recreating the widget.

Comment: In case you just want to update the buttons, you may use the `button.config()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bryan Oakley's comment, it's not really clear what you want to do.
In case if you want to completely remove all the `Button`s and recreate them,
you can use `Frame widget` and create `Button`s ON the `Frame`
and just remove `Frame` before recreating the `Button`s:

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import randint


def get_numbers(frame):
    frame.destroy()
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    global numbers
    numbers = [randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(20)]
    print(numbers)
    draw_buttons(frame)


def draw_buttons(frame):
    for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
        button = Button(frame, text=str(number),
                        command=lambda: get_numbers(frame))
        button.grid(row=0, column=i)


numbers = []

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
get_numbers(frame)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep your buttons around and call `.destroy()` on them to remove them before drawing new ones.

```
numbers = []
buttons = []

def delete_buttons():
    global buttons
    for button in buttons:
        button.destroy()
    # Set to empty so we can use append later
    buttons = []

def draw_buttons(frame):
    global buttons
    for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
        button = Button(frame, text=str(number),
                        command=lambda: get_numbers(frame))
        button.grid(row=0, column=i)
        # Add our button to our buttons list
        buttons.append(button)
```

Then use this right before your draw_buttons() method

```py
delete_buttons()
draw_buttons(frame)
```